# Resources to understand Lebesgue measure of Brownian motion's path

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, brownian-motion, lebesgue-measure

[https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Hansen.pdf][page 12] and [peter morters][page 47]
Let $B$ be a stanrd Brownian Motion and $R$ a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \text{:  } R(x)=\mathcal{L}_{2}(B[0,1]\cap (x+B(t+2)-B(2)+B(1))$$
$$Y=B(2)-B(1)$$
$$\forall A \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ and  } x \in \mathbb{R}^2 A+x:=\{a+x/a\in A\}$$ my question is why
$$E(R(Y))=1/2pi\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-x^2/2}E(R(x))dx?$$

$Y$ is a gaussian random variable , why do we still have $E$ in the second part of the equality? how to proove the mesurability of $R$?

Currently I'm reading from Peter Morter's book to understand the Lebesgue measure and Hausdorff dimension of Brownian motion's path... if you possess any well detailed proofs or resources on this topic, I'd greatly appreciate your sharing.

Comment: did you have any specific questions about it? The "potential theory" and BM chapter in Peres-Morters goes into detail. There are many notes on this topic https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Hansen.pdf

Comment: Let $B$ be a standart brownian motion , and $R$ a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and take $x$ to the Lebesgue measure of $B[0,1]\cap (x+B(t+2)-B(2)+B(1))$ \\  $Y=B(2)-B(1)$ \\ why $E(R(Y))=1/2pi\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-|x|^2}E(R(x))dx$

Comment: @sara ok I edit that in your question above.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452608/resources-to-understand-lebesgue-measure-of-brownian-motions-path#comment1170568_452608), what does "take $x$ to be the Lebesgue measure of [a set involving $x$]" mean?

Comment: @LSpice i mean for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ it give the Lebesgue measure of [a set involving  $x$]

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thank you so much

Comment: @sara you can edit your above post and add those details so that a person can answer it below. Specify what R is. and what you mean by x... do you mean any set A that contains x?

Comment: ok , i'll do that

Comment: To be clear the area of planar Brownian motion is zero.

Comment: What do you mean by the set inside the measure? Did you mean to write $x+B[0,t+2]-Y$?

Comment: Did you find this statement somewhere? Add the page reference in your above post if you did so that we can go read the original context

Comment: i add it , it existe in the reference that you shared with me too (page 12 ,a copy past from the book)

Comment: @sara ok I will try to answer it. But this is more of a textbook-question for https://math.stackexchange.com/. In the future, try to post them there. MO is more for research questions.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the notes ["BROWNIAN MOTION AND HAUSDORFF DIMENSION"](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Hansen.pdf) by Peter Hansen, he lets

$$R(x):=m_{2}(B_{1}[0,1]\cap (x+B_{2}([2,3])))$$

where $B_{1}(t):=B_{t}$ and $B_{2}(t):=B(t+2)-B_{2}+B_{1}$. The variable $Y:=B_{2}-B_{1}$ is independent of both BMs $B_{1},B_{2}$ by Markov property.

Then the claim is that

$$0=m_{2}(B_{1}[0,1]\cap (x+B_{2}([2,3])))=E[R(Y)]=(2\pi)^{-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^{2}/2}E[R(x)].$$

The first equality he proves it before. The second one is just definition. And the third equality follows because $Y\sim N(0,1)$ and it is independent of $X=B_{1}[0,1],B_{2}([2,3])$, and so by conditioning on them

$$E[R(Y)]=E[E[R(Y)|\sigma(X)]]=E[(2\pi)^{-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^{2}/2}R(x)dx]=(2\pi)^{-1}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^{2}/2}E[R(x)].$$

Comment: i got it , thank you so much